# Young adult novel with a forest in it

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

A young adult book with a green cover where a young girl is in a futuristic world (touch screens in the school she attended) and feels different and some how she runs away to a forest.  I remember reading this book quite a few years ago and just can't seem to find it.  There is one vivid scene that I remember: the girl bathes in a sort of oil and there is a description of the dirt just floating off of her (I think she was in a large wooden open air bath too). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have been looking for this exact same book!! I don't know what it is but I remember the scene where she bathed in the oil. If I find it I'll post the link. Doesn't she live with adopted parents and the touch screens are sort of grown?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect *The Secret Under My Skin* by Janet McNaughton (2000).

A teenage orphan in a post-apocalyptic 24th-century Newfoundland doesn't know anything about her origins except that her name might be something like 'Blay Raytee'. She works at a garbage dump digging for useful items, and has no reason to believe that she will ever do anything else. But a local biologist named Marella selects her to be an assistant and takes her to live in a nature preserve, where she takes a memorable bath (among other things). But as Blay's knowledge grows, she starts untangling her identity and also realising how totalitarian and messed up the society she came from still is. There's a sequel, too: *The Raintree Rebellion*.

Which [cover](http://www.janetmcnaughton.ca/Secretcover.html) you know depends on time and place, but the classic Canadian one has a forest-green spine with white letters.